# (C programming) bus error on my linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, scanf, singly-linked-list

I'm learning to use linkedlist, I feel I already understand the concept but when coding why do I always get an error (bus error)....this code can run, but only until "SCANF the NAME" after that an error appears.

```
typedef struct Student{
    char name[20];
    char idNum[10];
    int  saving;

    struct Student *next;
}Student;

Student *head = NULL;

void insert_student(){
    char *name,*idNum;
    int saving;

    Student *current;
    Student *new_student;
    new_student = (Student*)malloc(sizeof(Student));

    // apakah ada memoory kosong?
    if(new_student==NULL){
        printf("==== YOUR MEMMORY IS FULL! ====\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    printf("Enter your name     : ");scanf("%[^\n]s",name);
    printf("Enter your Id       : ");scanf("%[^\n]s",idNum);
    printf("How many your money : Rp");scanf("%d",&saving);

    strcpy(new_student->name,name);
    strcpy(new_student->idNum,idNum);
    new_student->saving = saving;

    new_student->next = NULL;

    if(head==NULL){
        head = new_student;
    }
    else{
        current = head;
        while (current->next != NULL)
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = new_student;
    }
}
void print_students(){
    Student *current;

    if(head==NULL){
        printf("==== THERE IS NO STUDENT YET!\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    current = head;
    while (current!= NULL)
    {
        printf("Name   : %s",current->name);
        printf("id     : %s",current->idNum);
        printf("Saving : Rp%d",current->saving);

        current = current->next;
    }
    
}

int main(){
    insert_student();
    print_students();
return 0;
}
```

I'm hoping to create nodes for the dynamic linked-list Student and then display them

Comment: Run your code in a debugger, and ask yourself what `name` points do when you do this: `scanf("%[^\n]s",name);` ? Likewise for `idNum` and this: `scanf("%[^\n]s",idNum);` Both of those pointers are *indeterminate*. They point to lord-knows-where, and your code invokes *undefined behavior* as a result. Consider yourself fortunate the code crashed; it could just as easily appeared to 'work' from the chaos of the whacky-wheel-of-mayhem, and *then* crashed on your grader's rig. [Turn up your warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/nzch6WrPq) and treat them as errors (because that's exactly what they are).

Comment: Unrelated, `scanf("%[^\n]s", name);` is nonsense. set-notation (which isn't even needed here) doesn't require, nor accept, a trailing `s`. [read the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) of the functions you're using.

Comment: @WhozCraig that's usually true but OP uses some odd architecture which can generate memory operation error. It might be SPARC, some ARMs or some more esoteric. SOme of those have unusual extensions of scanf\printf or unusual malloc\realloc behaviour. THat's also might be reason they don't see warnings. a  gcc-4.5 based "lcc" compiler for a custom SPARC I dealt with surely had no static checker at all.

Comment: Just to elaborate on @WhozCraig's somewhat terse remark: `scanf("%[^\n]", charPtr)` *alone* constitutes a complete *conversion specification* (which instructs scanf to copy all characters from stdin up to but not including the line ending into the memory starting at `charPtr`, which is probably what you wanted). That is, in the the *conversion specification* '%[...]', the `[...]` is a *conversion specifier* just like `s` is a conversion specifier in `%s`. ...

Comment: ... The '[...]' *replaces* the `s`. Consequently, the `s` you put after `[...]` stands alone as a single literal character which is expected to be in the input after the matched input before that. Apparently, scanf simply returns normally when the `s` does not materialize, no damage done; but it's probably not what you thought the code is doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
  printf("Enter your name     : ");scanf("%[^\n]s",name);
  printf("Enter your Id       : ");scanf("%[^\n]s",idNum);
```

You have to give `named` and `idNum` meaningful values before you pass their values to `scanf`. Instead, you are just passing uninitialized garbage value to `scanf`, which won't work. You must pass to `scanf` pointers to the place you want the strings you're reading in to be stored.

Answer (score 1):

For starters it is a bad idea to make the functions to depend on the global variable `head`. In this case you will not be able to use more than one list in  the program.

Within the function `insert_student` you declared uninitialized pointers `name` and `idNum`:

```
char *name,*idNum;
```

So using them in the calls of `scanf`

```
printf("Enter your name     : ");scanf("%[^\n]s",name);
printf("Enter your Id       : ");scanf("%[^\n]s",idNum);
```

invokes undefined behavior.

You need to declare character arrays instead of pointers

```
char name[20], idNum[10];
```

Also the format specifications are incorrect.

You should write

```
printf("Enter your name     : "); scanf( " %19[^\n]", name );
printf("Enter your Id       : "); scanf( " %9[^\n]", idNum );
```

Pay attention to the leading space in the format strings  It allows to skip white space characters.

Otherwise after this call of scanf

```
printf("How many your money : Rp");scanf("%d",&saving);
```

the input buffer will contain the new line character `'\n'`. So when you will call the function `insert_student` a second time the first call of `scanf` (if the format specification does not contain the leading space)

```
printf("Enter your name     : "); scanf( "%19[^\n]", name );
```

will read an empty string.

Also it is not a flexible approach when the whole program exits if a new node was not allocated.

```
if(new_student==NULL){
    printf("==== YOUR MEMMORY IS FULL! ====\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

It will be better to return to the caller an integer that will report whether the function was executed successfully. For example

```
int insert_student( void )
{
    //...
    Student *new_student;
    new_student = (Student*)malloc(sizeof(Student));
   
    int success = new_student != NULL;

    if ( success )
    { 
        printf("Enter your name     : ");scanf("%[^\n]s",name);
        printf("Enter your Id       : ");scanf("%[^\n]s",idNum);
        printf("How many your money : Rp");scanf("%d",&saving);
        //...
    }

    return success;
}
```